# Why would the value from a javascript selector be returned but undefined using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form called `myForm` I'm making as an exercise to get better at Javascript and jquery.  Inside my form I have a set of radio buttons that act as boolean values to show or hide other content (in this case, 2 `div`s that contain a table).

I wanted to tidy up the code a bit using jquery selectors rather than the entire `document.get` javascript way.  I'm doing this inside an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application if that matters.

The following code correctly grabs the value of my radio buttons

My view

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="radio" asp-for="AssignExtension" name="AssignExtension" value='true' onclick="assignExtensionSelect('true')" /> Yes
     <input type="radio" asp-for="AssignExtension" name="AssignExtension" value='false' onclick="assignExtensionSelect('false')" /> No
</div>
```

site.js

```
    <script>
        function assignExtensionSelect(extRequired) {
            let formInput = document.getElementById("myForm");
            //let formInput = $("#myForm");
            console.log(formInput.AssignExtension.value);

        if (extRequired) {
            $('#ifassignextension').show();
            $('#ifnotassignextension').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#ifassignextension').hide();
            $('#ifnotassignextension').show();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

The commented line is the one that won't work correctly.  Why does the code return `undefined` when I have `formInput = $("#myForm");` but works as expected when I assign the variable using the `document.getElementById` syntax?

Note: I have jquery already included in the view and other functions already using it, so this is not a dependency issue or jquery not being loaded.

Comment: `$('#ifassignextension')` returns a jQuery object, `classList` is a DOM property, not jQuery.

Comment: `$('#ifassignextension').removeClass("hidden")`

Comment: You can't use DOM properties and methods on jQuery objects. Pick one or the other approach and stick with it.

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong code.  The if/else block works fine, it's the one commented out line and the line above it that I'm asking about.

Comment: Is `myForm` a unique ID in the document?

Comment: The commented line has the same problem. `$("#myForm")` returns a jQuery object, it deosn't have an `AssignExtension` property. That's a property of the DOM element.

Comment: @Jacob Yes it is unique.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you.  Is there a way to do similar in jquery then?

Comment: You can use `$("#myForm")[0]` to get the corresponding DOM element.

Comment: Are you sure `$("#myForm")` is returning undefined? Seems more like `$("#myForm").AssignExtension.value` is undefined, right?

Comment: `$("#myForm").find("[name=AssignExtension]").val()`

Comment: @Jacob Yes, sorry I thought it was clear in the comment the code being returned is a console log statement.  You are correct, the `#myForm` is not undefined - it is the statement I'm attempting to log to the console that shows undefined.

Comment: @Barmar Your solutions worked.  If you wanted to expand a bit on them and make them into a single answer, I will mark it as accepted.  Thanks for explaining this, now I know some differences to look for when doing things in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use DOM properties with jQuery objects. If you're using jQuery, you have to use its selectors and methods.

```
let formInput = $("#myForm");
console.log(formInput.find("[name=AssignExtension]:checked").val());
```